# nginx: rewriting rule to access Mattermost instance

Tags: nginx, configuration, mattermost

I have a VPS whose primary interface is accessible via two internet names which I'll give here as personal.me and company.com.  I am running a Mattermost server and can access it via personal.me using the following nginx rule:

```
server {
    server_name personal.me;

        location / {
            client_max_body_size 50M;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8065;
        }
    }
```

This is working perfectly well but I would also like to access the instance via http://company.com/fora/ -- the point being that this time there is a /fora/ path to remove.  I know that I should be using https:// but that is a separate matter, for later.  I tried:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  company.com;

    location / {
        root   [...];
        index  index.html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location /fora/ {
        client_max_body_size 50M;
        rewrite /fora/ / break;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   X-Frame-Options   SAMEORIGIN;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8065;
    }
}
```

but when I navigate to http://company.com/fora/ although the title-bar changes to Mattermost, there is no content --- the page is blank.  Since I can access Mattermost via the personal.me URL, I believe that Mattermost is running correctly.

What is wrong with the company.com rule?  Is it something to do with not passing the path into Mattermost?

According to [Nginx reverse proxy (proxy_pass) does not pass subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650640/nginx-reverse-proxy-proxy-pass-does-not-pass-subfolder) and http://forum.mattermost.org/t/blank-page-when-installing-mattermost-with-nginx-proxy-pass-as-subdirectory/1604 this isn't possible but I don't get that ... surely removing a bit of the URL is one of nginx's core capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be impossible with Mattermost currently as the app assumes it is at the server root.

See [this issue on their github](https://github.com/mattermost/platform/issues/643) and [this ticket](https://mattermost.atlassian.net/browse/PLT-200) for further details and to track when/if this becomes a supported feature.

Comment: I don't understand this;   isn't the point of the nginx 'rewrite' rule that Mattermost sees the rewritten URL and doesn't know it's not at the server root ?

Answer (score 0):

What we do is create a subdomain for each mattermost service we want to access on a domain. I suggest creating a subdomain fora.company.com then use that subdomain in your nginx settings.